# Rename json keys iterative

Tags: javascript, json

I got a very simple json but in each block I got something like this.

```
var json = {
"name": "blabla"
"Children": [{
      "name": "something"
      "Children": [{ ..... }]
}
```

And so on. I don't know how many children there are inside each children recursively.

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);

for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    var key = keys[j];
    var value = json[key];
    delete json[key];
    key = key.replace("Children", "children");
    json[key] = value;
}
```

And now I want to replace all "Children" keys with lowercase "children". The following code only works for the first depth. How can I do this recursively?

Comment: Maybe a hack and not the answer you are after but how about: `var s = JSON.stringify(json); var t = s.replace(/"Children"/g, '"children"'); var newJson = JSON.parse(t);` ?

Comment: Thank you @Bardy. worked like a charm

Comment: Yay! no probs! :)

Comment: @Bardy why it cannot be answer ??

Comment: OK. I add as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
var s = JSON.stringify(json);
var t = s.replace(/"Children"/g, '"children"');
var newJson = JSON.parse(t);
```

- **Pros:** This solution is very simple, being just three lines.
- **Cons:** There is a *potential* unwanted side-effect, consider:

  ```
  var json = {
    "name": "blabla",
    "Children": [{
      "name": "something",
      "Children": [{ ..... }]
    }],
    "favouriteWords": ["Children","Pets","Cakes"]
  }
  ```

The solution replaces *all* instances of `"Children"`, so the entry in the `favouriteWords` array would also be replaced, despite **not** being a property name. If there is no chance of the word appearing anywhere else other than as the property name, then this is not an issue, but worth raising just in case.

Answer (score 3):

It looks the input structure is pretty well-defined, so you could simply create a recursive function like this:

```js
function transform(node) {
  return {
    name: node.name,
    children: node.Children.map(transform)
  };
}


var json = {
  "name": "a",
  "Children": [{
    "name": "b",
    "Children": [{
      "name": "c",
      "Children": []
    }, {
      "name": "d",
      "Children": []
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "e",
    "Children": []
  }]
};

console.log(transform(json));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that can do it recursivly:

```
 function convertKey(obj) {
    for (objKey in obj)
    {

        if (Array.isArray(obj[objKey])) {
            convertKey[objKey].forEach(x => {
                convertKey(x);
            });

        }

        if (objKey === "Children") {
            obj.children = obj.Children;
            delete obj.Children;
        }
    }
 }
```

And here is a more generic way for doing this:

```
function convertKey(obj, oldKey, newKey) {
    for (objKey in obj)
    {

        if (Array.isArray(obj[objKey])) {
            obj[objKey].forEach(objInArr => {
                convertKey(objInArr);
            });
        }

        if (objKey === oldKey) {
            obj[newKey] = obj[oldKey];
            delete obj[oldKey];
        }
    }
}

convertKey(json, "Children", "children");
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the accepted answer, and @Tamas answer have slight issues.

With @Bardy's answer like he points out, there is the issue if any of your values's had the word Children it would cause problems.

With @Tamas, one issue is that any other properties apart from name & children get dropped.  Also it assumes a Children property. And what if the children property is already `children` and not `Children`.

Using a slightly modified version of @Tamas, this should avoid the pitfalls.

```js
function transform(node) {
  if (node.Children) node.children = node.Children;
  if (node.children) node.children = node.children.map(transform);
  delete node.Children;
  return node;
}


var json = {
  "name": "a",
  "Children": [{
    "age": 13,
    "name": "b",
    "Children": [{
      "name": "Mr Bob Chilren",
      "Children": []
    }, {
      "name": "d",
      "age": 33,  //other props keep
      "children": [{
        "name": "already lowecased",
        "age": 44,
        "Children": [{
           "name": "now back to upercased",
           "age": 99
        }]
      }] //what if were alrady lowercased?
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "e",
    //"Children": []  //what if we have no children
  }]
};

console.log(transform(json));
```